# Trying to run Strapi project

Tags: strapi

Thank you for your help,

- Strapi Version: 4.15.4
- Operating System: Mac OS 12.7.1 (Monterey)
- Database: SQLite
- Node Version: v18.16.1
- NPM Version: 9.5.1

0. I downloaded my Strapi project from my Github repo,
1. I made `npm install`
2. Copied the .env file

and run `npm run develop`

but I get the following error:

[ERROR]  There seems to be an unexpected error, try again with --debug for more information

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')
at Module.getNonVisibleAttributes (/Users/carlosraulcarcamotejada/Downloads/strapi-afp-main/node_modules/@strapi/utils/dist/index.js:754:11)

at getNestedFields (/Users/carlosraulcarcamotejada/Downloads/strapi-afp-main/node_modules/@strapi/admin/server/services/content-type.js:30:51)

at /Users/carlosraulcarcamotejada/Downloads/strapi-afp-main/node_modules/@strapi/admin/server/services/content-type.js:43:31

at /Users/carlosraulcarcamotejada/Downloads/strapi-afp-main/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:928:11

at /Users/carlosraulcarcamotejada/Downloads/strapi-afp-main/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4967:15

at baseForOwn (/Users/carlosraulcarcamotejada/Downloads/strapi-afp-main/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:3032:24)

at /Users/carlosraulcarcamotejada/Downloads/strapi-afp-main/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4936:18

at baseReduce (/Users/carlosraulcarcamotejada/Downloads/strapi-afp-main/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:925:5)

at Function.reduce (/Users/carlosraulcarcamotejada/Downloads/strapi-afp-main/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9749:14)

at getNestedFields(/Users/carlosraulcarcamotejada/Downloads/strapi-afp-main/node_modules/@strapi/admin/server/services/content-type.js:32:12)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IW2b.png)

read all results from google

Comment: I found the solution , gitignore includes file call Icon, so I have a component call Icon and when I Download from Github it came without those file call icon, son when I run “npm run develop” I get error or if I try to import the database.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with the `strapi/utils` module. Can you maybe update your question to tell the `@strapi/utils` version you are using in your `package.json` ?

I recommand you to try using `"@strapi/utils": "^4.15.5"` if it is not the case.

It looks like you are using deprecated version of Strapi, an `npm update` would be great too